# Deployment on Windows Azure fails if I add a <VirtualApplication>

Tags: azure

I have an Azure deployment that has been running since several months. I changed and re-deployed it several times without any issues.

Now I'm trying to add a second Web Application to the same deployment. I followed the blog post at http://sanganakauthority.blogspot.ch/2012/02/hosting-multiple-virtual-applications.html, which describes how to add a second Web Application by adding a `<VirtualDirectory ...>` tag to the service definition:

```
<WebRole name="MyWebsite1">
  <Sites>
    <Site name="Web">
      <VirtualApplication name="MyWebsite2" physicalDirectory="..\..\WebProject2\WebProject2"></VirtualApplication>
    <Bindings>
    ...
```

I did that, and in the Azure Emulator, everything works fine. I can access the first web application at

```
http://127.0.0.2:81
```

and the new, virtual one at

```
http://127.0.0.2:81/MyWebsite2
```

But when I deploy to Azure, I get the following deployment error in the Azure Console of Visual Studio:

```
10:55:33 - Preparing deployment for {...} with Subscription ID: {...}...
10:55:33 - Connecting...
10:55:34 - Uploading Certificates...
10:56:08 - Verifying storage account '{...}'...
10:56:09 - Uploading Package...
11:00:04 - The HTTP request to 'https://management.core.windows.net/{...}/services/hostedservices/{...}?embed-detail=true' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
11:00:04 - Deployment failed with a fatal error
```

When I remove the `<VirtualApplication>` tag from the service definition, then the deployment is working again, like before.

**How can I find out the cause of this error? The error happens before the instance is started, so RDP doesn't help.**

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it worked when I created a second `<Site>` instead of the `<VirtualApplication>`:

```
<WebRole name="MyWebsite1">
  <Sites>
    <Site name="Web">
      <Bindings>
      ...
    </Site>
    <Site name="MyWebsite2" physicalDirectory="..\..\WebProject2\WebProject2">
      <Bindings>
      ...
    </Site>
  </Sites>
  ...
```